Measure Problem and ZFC, is the existence of a measure on a set provable?
Let PMT be the statement "There exists a set on which there exists a measure" which is an affirmative answer to the Measure Problem.
We know that the existence of inaccessible cardinals is not provable in ZFC, and that the continuum hypothesis is independent from ZFC.
In Jech's Set Theory book, Ulam theorem says "If there is a $\sigma$-additive nontrivial measure (aka a measure) on a set $S$, then either there exists a two-valued measure on $S$ and $|S|$ is greater than or equal to the least inaccessible cardinal, or there exists an atomless measure on $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ is greater than or equal to the least weakly inaccessible cardinal."
And corollary 10.17 says "If there is a measure on $2^{\aleph_0}$, then $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_1$".
So if we can prove PMT in ZFC, it would imply either $\neg$CH or the existence of inaccessible cardinals. But neither is provable in ZFC, so we can say that PMT is not provable in ZFC right?

Yes, that’s right (provided the consistency of ZFC, of course, and with the caveat that we’re only talking about measures with respect to the entire power set.)

You could also infer from the  weakly inaccessible rather than not CH in the atomless case, which gives a better sense of the strength of the proposition / size of the reals in this case. (Though it’s actually much stronger than that.)

A measure needs to be defined on a nonempty set with a particular sigma algebra. Any nonempty set $\Omega$ trivially has a measure when we use sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}={\Omega, \phi}$. Also, any finite set $\Omega$ trivially has a measure when we use the power set sigma algebra.

@Michael the (not explicitly stated) assumption here is we’re talking about finite measures on the whole power set which are not the zero measure and have all singletons measuring zero.

I see that "all singletons measuring zero" rules out finite or countable sets $\Omega$. That (unstated) assumption seems to be very important! It is unusual to leave it unstated. The OP statement "There exists a set on which there exists a measure" is not the statement of interest here.
